# Google Play Support

Tags: google-play-services

When installing a game from Google Play I am asked to login to Google play services to update. Unfortunately the email account linked to this is one I had at school which no longer exists. How do I access Google Play services to update it without this email. I have tried uninstalling but this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually install it by downloading the corresponding play services on this page

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/

Comment: Thanks Kenji but I already have Google Play Services installed. The problem is that I can't sign into it as the email linked to is is no longer functioning. I need to either bypass the sign-in or unistall it.

Comment: depending on the device, some of them allow you to uninstall from settings -> applications -> play services, other devices force you to deactivate them from the play store. What you can do is delete your email account by entering settings -> accounts -> google -> delete account

Comment: This video show how dissable and install other play services https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEPYhe-ZyjY